# Unwanted padding between views with background gradient

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-relativelayout

I want to assign gradient to background of LinearLayouts. Everything looks good except padding in bottom and between LinearLayouts.

This layout I use for ViewPager for showing images.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo_pager_fragment_image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/likeBottomLayout"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/likeImage"
                android:background="@color/transparentWhite"
                android:src="@drawable/post_like"
                android:paddingLeft="14dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:clickable="false" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/commentsBottomLayout"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/comment"
                android:background="@color/transparentWhite"
                android:src="@drawable/post_comment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:paddingRight="7dp"
                android:paddingLeft="7dp"
                android:clickable="false" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/repostBottomLayout"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background">
            <ImageButton
                android:background="@color/transparentWhite"
                android:src="@drawable/post_repost"
                android:paddingRight="14dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:clickable="false" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

background.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
      <item  android:state_focused="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
    </selector>
```

normal.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#99000000"
      android:endColor="#00000000"
      android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

pressed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color = "@color/tranparent_light_gray"/>
</shape>
```

[image]

How to remove this padding?.

p.s. In the dark photos I don't see this padding. I think because it is transparent color.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the padding of your buttons and their parents, and margins if any.

Comment: Thanks for response. I remove all margin and padding but it n't helps.
But if I ran on Pre-lollipop(4.3) - all works good without any padding and margin. And on android 5.1 I get this strange padding